# Call powershell function with parameters piped from an array of hash tables

Tags: powershell

Consider this array of hash tables (edited to feature fixes from @mclayton):

```
$some_keys= @(
    @{
        foo="one";
        bar="some other stuff";
    },
    # (...more entries...)
    @{
        foo="two";
        bar="some more stuf";
    }
)
```

Also, consider the following function:

```
function Get-WithKeys($foo, $bar){
    # do stuff with $foo, $bar
}
```

Does Powershell provide any idiomatic way to pipe `some_keys` so that `Get-WithKeys` is called once per array element with the hashmap's keys passed as function parameters?

For illustration purposes, I'm wondering if Powershell offers something for this effect:

```
$some_keys | <magic step> | Get-WithKeys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "splatting" - see [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2).

Basically, you call the function with a hashtable variable as a parameter, but prefix it with `@` instead of `$` and each key in the hashtable is treated as a named parameter.

A simple example:

```sh
$my_hashtable = @{
    foo="one";
    bar="some other stuff"
}

# equivalent to Get-WithKeys -foo "one" -bar "some other stuff"
Get-WithKeys @my_hashtable
```

In your original sample you could do this to call `Get-WithKeys` once per item in your `$some_keys` array:

```sh
$some_keys | foreach-object { Get-WithKeys @_ }
```

Where `@_` is using the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) `$_` as the variable to splat.